# Symfony2 Registration Form User Entity

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a registration form using my "User" entity, but the UserType form contains a lot of extra fields I don't want to be completed on the registration form.

Do I need to create a second Form Type to pull this off?

i.e. One of the fields in the UserType form is "account_status" which tracks whether the account has been approved by an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

[How to implement a simple Registration Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html)

Here you can see an example of creating a registration form. The full `UserType` is not for registration, it's for an admin to create the user. Obviously you don't want the user to set his/her account status during the registration process.

You can set theese variables in the `RegistrationController`, and you should create a new `UserType` for user registraion.

If you don't want to use the `accountStatus` method, you should set it to true during the registration in the controller.